# Horizontal context menu with icons Windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, contextmenu

I am trying to add a **context menu** which shows menu items horizontally. My sample code:

```
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <toolkit:MenuItem Tap="CallMenuItem_tapped">
                <toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
                    <Image Height="50"
                           Stretch="Uniform"
                           Source="Assets/icon1.png" />
                </toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
            </toolkit:MenuItem>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Tap="ChatMenuItem_tapped">
                <toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
                    <Image Height="50"
                           Stretch="Uniform"
                           Source="Assets/icon2.png" />
                </toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
            </toolkit:MenuItem>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Tap="OtherMenuItem_tapped">
                <toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
                    <Image Height="50"
                           Stretch="Uniform"
                           Source="Assets/icon3.png" />
                </toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
            </toolkit:MenuItem>
        </StackPanel>
    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

I am facing some problems. First of all when I tap a menu item the specific event is called but the menu remains open. As I am showing all the menu items in one line(horizontally), I am unable to fix the height and width of context menu. Is there a better way to add a horizontal **context menu** using icons?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the ItemsPanel property to set the layout as horizontal stack panel. And if you still face any issues then you can manually close the context menu using the IsOpen property. Hope this helps you.